# How many times does each word is repeated in a string in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have declared a string as shown below:

```
Declare @string
Set @string = 'this line is like this because this is repeated these many times in this line'
```

I am trying find that how many times each word is repeated. I am expecting a result like

```
Word   Number
this    x times
line    y times
is      z times
```

and so on...

Help me with the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit:

So far, I have got to the point of find number words in which a particular alphabet is replaced.

Here is the code of it

```
SELECT Len(@string) - Len(Replace(@string, 'x', '')).
```

Any explanation along with the provided code will be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you're having trouble with some specific code, then most people will be happy to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To be honest I am new to sql. So far I have got to the point of understanding how to find number words in which a particular alphabet is replaced. I will post the code in edit.

Comment: @MycrowSoft no worries, let me try to write a query for your issue.

Comment: @TomH Thank you for the link, I will definitely go through it and try to correct myself next time when i am posting a question.

Comment: @ChiragThakar Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH splitString(val) AS       
(
    -- convert the string to xml, seperating the elements by spaces
    SELECT    CAST('<r><i>' + REPLACE(@string,' ','</i><i>') + '</i></r>' AS XML)
)
SELECT  [Key],
        COUNT(*) [WordCount]
FROM    (   -- select all of the values from the xml created in the cte
            SELECT  p.value('.','varchar(100)') AS [Key]
            FROM    splitString
                    CROSS APPLY val.nodes('//i') t (p)) AS t
GROUP BY [Key]
```

if you want to get all technical..

```
;WITH splitString(val) AS       
(
    -- convert the string to xml, seperating the elements by spaces
    SELECT    CAST('<r><i>' + REPLACE(@string,' ','</i><i>') + '</i></r>' AS XML)
)
SELECT  Word,
        CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR) 
            + (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN ' time' ELSE ' times' END) AS  Number
FROM    (   -- select all of the values from the xml created in the cte
            SELECT  p.value('.','varchar(100)') AS Word
            FROM    splitString
                    CROSS APPLY val.nodes('//i') t (p)) AS t
GROUP BY Word
```

Comment: Worked perfect, Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Using a t-sql splitter this is pretty straight forward. My personal preference is the Jeff Moden splitter which can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ There are some other options which can be found here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Using Jeff Moden's it is this simple.

```
Declare @string varchar(1000)
Set @string = 'this line is like this because this is repeated these many times in this line'

select x.Item
    , COUNT(*) as WordCount
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string, ' ') x
group by x.Item
order by x.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that may solve your issue.

First you run below function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(

 @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items

, @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ' ' -- delimiter that separates items

 ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

 BEGIN

 DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0

 BEGIN

 SELECT

 @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,

    @sInputList,0)-1))),

 @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,

    @sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0

 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem

 END

 IF LEN(@sInputList)> 0

 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in

 RETURN

 END
```

Now you run this code

```
Declare @string Varchar(MAX)
Set @string = 'this line is like this because this is repeated these many times in this line'

DECLARE @Words AS TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Words VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Words
select * from fnSplit(@string, ' ')

SELECT Words AS Word, COUNT(*) Number FROM @Words GROUP BY Words ORDER BY Number DESC
```

Comment: @MycrowSoft okay. its My pleasure, i always try to be helpful.

Comment: That will work but that type of splitter is the absolute worst for performance.

Comment: @SeanLange sure, i will try to improve this. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Here are some better options for splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings When you see a cursor or a while loop in a splitter it is not going to scale well. Such is the nature of set based operations. :)

Comment: You can also take a look at the link in my answer about Tally Table.

Comment: @SeanLange yes, i did.